# Path parameters being passed as a String with comma not read properly in rest assured

Tags: rest-assured

I have a code where I am passing path parameters in the GET request in Rest Assured. But I see the path parameters aren't read properly and I see some gibberish text being read. Actually the String I am passing as path parameter contains a comma in it. Below is my code.

```
ValidatableResponse response = given().header("Authorization", token).header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .when().log().all().pathParam("CalendarId", testCaseBean.getCalendarId().toString())
                .queryParam("from", testCaseBean.getStartDate()).queryParam("to", testCaseBean.getEndDate())
                .queryParam("monthEnd", testCaseBean.getMonthEndBusinessDay())
                .get(EndPoint.GET_CALENDAR_BUSINESS_DAY_INFO_DATE_PARAM).then().log().all();
```

The path param I am passing is "AUS,EUR" and it is being read as AUS%2CEUR. I am passing this path parameter as test data from the CSV file. Below is the request being formed on the console.

```
https://portculation-qa.us-east-1.m5435454345.easn.mss.com/master-data/v1/calendars/AUS%2CEUR?from=2022-11-01&to=2022-11-01&monthEnd=false
```

My expected request URI is `https://portculation-qa.us-east-1.m5435454345.easn.mss.com/master-data/v1/calendars/AUS,EUR?from=2022-11-01&to=2022-11-01&monthEnd=false`

You can see the only difference in the expected and actual URI is the gibberish path param which isn't read properly. Any solution to tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
.urlEncodingEnabled(false)

RestAssured.given()
.contentType(JSON)
.log()
.all()
.urlEncodingEnabled(false)
```

or:

```
RestAssured.urlEncodingEnabled = false;
```

By default it set to true.